# Creating new properties at Run Time in VB.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net, properties

Is it possible to create new properties at Run Time in .Net

It is a Win Form app. I have many fields in this form that are populated from an XML settings file that is read in. Once the user is finished filling out these fields they click a 'save' button. This then writes all the information on the form back to the XML file as well as setting a bunch of public shared properties of a different class.

My issue is, On the form I have a Data Grid View. Each row in this data grid view needs to be a property of this different class. The user is able to add rows to this data grid and I want properties made of these newly added rows.

Comment: you could create a data table and add columns dynamically to the table and then access these columns as and when you need to. Just an idea..

Comment: Please clarify your question and be as specific as possible. Exclude your thoughts from the question, only facts. Avoid indeterminate phrases, such as `add things`, `through the list in the places`, `want properties made of [...] rows` etc. Right now your are risking to get closed as 'not a real question'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add properties to class at run-time. But you could save the properties in a datasource and use the class to read/write those properties.